# Why do comments get moved from answer to question?

Tags: bug, convert-to-comment

At the time of writing, this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954747/msil-
insertion-in-dotnet has one answer, which has now been deleted.

Prior to deletion, there were two comments applied to the answer.

Following deletion, these two comments now appear both as comments on the answer AND comments on the question, where they make no sense at all.

Why would SO duplicate a comment onto an entity on which it isn't commenting?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7):

A moderator converted the answer to [a comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954747/msil-insertion-in-dotnet#comment17562078_12954747).  When we do that, we have the option of moving all the comments on the answer along with it, which is what happened here.  They're replies to the answer (now a comment), so I think it does make sense to keep them.

Comment: The OP here is correct, those two comments are now out of context. Looks like a feature request should be started asking to add @[author here] in the beginning of such comments. Can you do that manually for now to prevent the confusion?

Comment: OK, thanks - I don't think the moderator really knows what they're doing in this specific case - the actually answer part of the answer is just plain irrelevant, but I guess the moderator saw a question within the answer and triggered their 'should be a comment' mechanism.  Oh how I've grown to dislike SO...

Comment: @Will there isn't automatic mechanism; users flagged the answer that's all.

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard - I'd like to be able to put something into *my* comments which prevented a moderator being able to move them to somewhere where they have no context and make me look like a dribbling idiot.  (I'm happy to do the latter myself, but I don't want it done for me...)

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard - the 'mechanism' I referred to was the biomechanical one within the moderator.

Comment: @Will this is an unavoidable side impact of the answer being converted to comment. You can still delete your own comment if you like. (oh, I see you just did)

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard - I have done, thanks - I just don't want to have to review every comment I've ever made to see if some chump has moved it to somewhere where it makes no sense.

Comment: @WillDean "if some chump has moved it"...you might want to rephrase that slightly more politely next time.

Comment: @Will well, you'll have to accept at some point that this is community driven site with moderation. Ordinary users are flagging answers and moderators heed those flags. If you feel uncomfortable with the concept nobody is holding you here by force. If you really believe that answer should be answer and not comment you can flag it explaining your reasons and other moderator might agree and undelete it.

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard - Sure - I'm not clear that anyone flagged that answer as 'should be a comment instead of an answer' though - there were two downvotes and two comments, both indicating that it was the answer to a different question (i.e. the answerer had probably answered before completely understanding a question).